# Regular Expression to isolate an html tag

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, html, regex

I'm looking for a regular expression to isolate an html tag. This includes the TAG the ATTRIBUTES and the CONTNET inside.

Let's say I have this:

```
<html> 
<body>
aajsdfkjaskd 
<TAGNAME name="bla" context="non">hfdfhdj </TAGNAME>
</body>
 </html>
```

I need a regular expression that would return:

```
<TAGNAME name="bla" context="non">hfdfhdj </TAGNAME>
```

Thank,
Joe

Comment: [Don't use regexes for parsing HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: In the **general** case, that's not possible.  If there are specific constraints on the nature of the HTML surrounding and/or contained in the tag, you should describe those.

Comment: @Pointy: I believe this to be possible in C# regex (which support balanced matching). And I believe, that nobody really wants to do that =)

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a regex, use an HTML parser instead. Much more reliable and easier to work with.

If you're a PHP developer I recommend you use this one (http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

Look into [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) it will make things a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

use this regex `<TAGNAME.+?</TAGNAME>`

Comment: Just make sure there are no nested `TAGNAME`s

Comment: So what about `<TAGNAME foo="xyz">Hello world <TAGNAME>banana</TAGNAME>`

Comment: it's catch outer tag with inner inside

Answer (score 0):

If this is the main thing you're trying to do, XLST is a good tool to do it with. 
You can easily select just TAGNAME and copy over the attributes and text.
See http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/ for an intro.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: don't do this. Parsing HTML with regex is a maintenance nightmare and will most probably fail on any real world example of HTML. There are better options (like using a HTML parser like the [HTML Agility pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)).

To answer your question though, the following regex will do what you want **if** the HTML code

- is well formed (no missing closing tag, etc)
- does not contain comments with "TAGNAME" in them
- does not contain script blocks with "TAGNAME" in them
- maybe more

It can be expanded to cover some of these cases, but you really don't want to =)

```xml
    <TAGNAME(<TAGNAME (?<tagcounter>)|</TAGNAME>(?<-tagcounter>)|.)*</TAGNAME>(?(tagcounter)(?!))
```

You'd need `RegexOptions.SingleLine`, too. See it in action at [Ideone.com](http://ideone.com/Z6SFQ)